# How do I integrate  Flash with Php

Tags: php, mysql, flash

I want to integrate my flash file with php code. I got the below code from

> http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/flashphpxml_integration2.htm

```
function lv(l, n, t, e, f) {
    if (l == undefined) {
        l = new LoadVars();
        l.onLoad = function () {
            var i;
            n.htmlText = "";
            if (t == undefined) {
                n.htmlText += "<b>" + this["title" + e] + "</b><br>";
            } else {
                for (i = 0; i < this.n; i++) {
                    n.htmlText += "<a href='" + this["link" + i] + "'>" + this["title" + i] + "</a><br>";
                }
            }
        };
    }
    l.load(f);
}
lv(sites_txt, "cycle", null, "sites.php");
```

I did all the steps given in that forum but while running that code i got error Like

```
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method LoadVars.

Warning: 1060: Migration issue: The method LoadVars is no longer supported.  For more information, see the URLVariables class, the URLRequest.urlVariables and URLRequest.postData properties, and the URLLoader.dataFormat property..

1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 5.
```

I am new to the flash scripting please guide me how to troublshooting these

Comment: LoadVars is an AS2 class - I'll show you an AS3 example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example code was in AS2, here's how you send and receive data from and to PHP using AS3 using:

1. URLRequest
2. URLLoader
3. URLVariables

Here's a quick class I have made for you:

```
package
{
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class PHPData extends Object
    {
        /**
         * Sends data to a PHP script
         * @param script A URL to the PHP script
         */
        public function send(script:String, vars:URLVariables):void
        {
            var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(script);

            req.data = vars;
            req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.load(req);

            // listeners
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);
        }

        /**
         * Called when a response has been received from a PHP script
         * @param e Event.COMPLETE
         */
        private function _complete(e:Event):void
        {
            var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(e.target.data);

            var i:String;
            for(i in vars)
            {
                trace(i + ": " + vars[i]);
            }

            e.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _complete);
        }
    }
}
```

With this, you can send data to a given PHP script in the format of `URLVariables`.

`URLVariables` are easily prepared like so:

```
var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

vars.myvar = "some value";
vars.myothervar = 30;
```

Here's a quick example I have mocked up for you which sends a string to PHP, then PHP sends back the string hashed as MD5 and also has a timestamp attached as a secondary value.

```
var php:PHPData = new PHPData();

var vars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
vars.myvar = "marty";

php.send("http://projectavian.com/md5.php", vars);
```

Your output for this will be something similar to:

```
response: bb3761a33402b4f82806178e79ec5261
time: 1306133172
```

Just alter the `_complete` method in the `PHPData` class to handle your response data as required :)

---

I'll throw this in because your question has the **mysql** tag..

All you need to do is your standard INSERT and SELECT queries in the PHP script and encode your result into this format:

```
var=1&other=2&more=three
```

So you could have..

```
<?php
    mysql_connect(/* ?? */);
    mysql_select_db(/* ?? */);

    // INSERT example
    $thing = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["thing"]);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('','$thing')");

    // SELECT for response
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["uid"]);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$uid' LIMIT 1");

    // send response
    $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo 'fname=' . $r["first_name"] . '&lname=' . $r["last_name"];
?>
```